# Find min(x1, x1*x2, x1*x2*x3, ..., x1*x2*...*xN) in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, min

`xi=exprnd(1,M,1), i=1,...,N`, is a column vector of `M x 1` size. This means that the `j-th` element of `xi` is `xi(j)>=0`.

I want to get the column vector X of Mx1 size where the `j-th` element of `X` is 
`X(j)=min[x1(j), x1(j)*x2(j), x1(j)*x2(j)*x3(j), ..., x1(j)*x2(j)*...*xN(j)]`.

Can anyone help me with MATLAB code which works for any `M` and `N`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build your vectors directly as columns of an *M*x*N* matrix:

```
xi = exprnd(1,M,N);
```

Then the desired result can be obtained computing the cumulative product along the second dimension ([`cumprod`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html)) and then minimizing along the second dimension ([`min`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html)):

```
result = min(cumprod(xi,2),[],2);
```